# Swift preprocessor if not flag

Tags: swift, preprocessor-directive

Is there a Swift compiler directive for `#if not`?

I know this could work

```swift
#if myFlag
    // ignore
#else 
    bar()
#endif
```

But it is not pretty if there is nothing between `if` and `else`.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

I wasn't trying enough, I found out

```
#if !myFlag 

#endif
```

works well !